# how can i generate reset password link with only access once and expiry some period of times

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am developing web application into java server page. Where i need link must be expire after some times of period and access only once. which will be sent to registered user mail id. i cant figure out how can i achieve this also not find appropriate solution on Google.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append a parameter to the link you send out with a random hash, storing this hash in a database table with the expiration date. Thereby generating a unqiue link that does only appy for one user for one occasion.

```
table:
id    timestamp             hash               userid    expiration
 1    21.10.2013 xx:xx:xx   jkl23h4hl2k34h     dummy     22.10.2013 xx:xx:xx
```

Whenever a password reset  is needed you check for this parameter in the lookup table, determine wether the expiration date is valid and serve a password reset mail.
Then you could delete the row ( Password reset occured, no longer needed) or you could set the expiration date to a value in the past, preserving the table as history of account resets( possibly adding the client ip address or similar)

Comment: thanks sir you helped me lot, but any another easy way to achieve this.How can i generate random hash.